# Unexpected multiple operator behavior in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, operators, bytecode

This question is asked out of purely curiosity/academic interest of Python as a language.

Suppose I have the following snippet:

```
>>> 1 in [1,2] == False
False
```

Which come out as expected as `in` takes precedence over `==` and 1 in [1,2] evaluates to `True`, and `True != False`.

But **behold**:

```
>>> 10 in [1,2] == False
False
```

Which is surprising because 10 in [1,2] evaluates to `False` and `False == False` should evaluates to `True`.

And I can prove that it is not because `==` is evaluated first, because it wouldn't even run:

```
>>> 10 in ([1,2] == False)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: argument of type 'bool' is not iterable
```

While if `in` statement is run first by parenthesis it *will* return `True`:

```
>>> (10 in [1,2]) == False
True
# Note: All of above work in the same way if numbers and list are substituted by variables.
```

I went to `dis` and discovered an interesting caveat:

```
def func(): return (x in y == False)
dis.dis(func)

          0 LOAD_FAST                0 (x)
          2 LOAD_FAST                1 (y)
          4 DUP_TOP
          6 ROT_THREE
          8 COMPARE_OP               6 (in)
         10 JUMP_IF_FALSE_OR_POP    18
         12 LOAD_CONST               1 (False)
         14 COMPARE_OP               2 (==)
         16 RETURN_VALUE
    >>   18 ROT_TWO
         20 POP_TOP
         22 RETURN_VALUE
```

The `JUMP_IF_FALSE_OR_POP` bytecode entirely skips the `==` part (to 18) if FALSE. However, doing `x in y == True` *also always* evaluate to True on essentially the same bytecode. What's more, This bytecode is not seen in either `in` or `==` operations, something has to be generating it.

So what exactly is going on here? Why does everything in the format of `x in y == (bool)` Always evaluate to `False`? And what's *actually* happening behind the scene?

Comment: Chaining comparison operators: have a look at `1 in (1, 2) == (1, 2)`.  In general, if you're using this for an `if` statement and the like you can just rely on the truthiness of the comparison instead of comparing it to `False` manually

Comment: Good find -- perfect answer.

Comment: **x < y < z is equivalent to x < y and y < z, and is evaluates from
left-to-right.**

Going off of that logic your expression without brackets is:

    `1 in [1,2] and [1,2] == False`